# Move existing WordPress install to Multisite

Tags: multisite

I would like to move my existing WordPress install to Multisite but unfortunately I've run into the redirect loop issue. I've been reading through the codex and realize that since my install has been around for longer than a month it will force the sub domain network option. Is there a way around this? I'd really like to use the sub directory option and avoid changing my url during the install. Can I ignore the suggestion to change my url and keep the www in my url?

I came across the section below in the Multisite Network Admin notes but I'm confused as to how this would work into the process:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Switching_network_types

Comment: You can build the WP multi-site and simply import your single WP site into the network.  I've done this more than once.

Comment: Yes, I guess this would be an option but starting with fresh install seems like it would lead to a lot of downtime.

Comment: Using a dev folder or similar would allow you to build the new WP MS and do your import work before switching from single to MS.  Are you running the current site in a /wordpress folder or in the root?

Comment: Current site runs in the root